# How to protect REST API when using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, api, rest, security

There are SNS application with 2 servers. Web backend server and REST API server.

1. The web server allows user login/logout with username/password, and show user information
2. The REST API server provides APIs like /topics, /comments, it should be stateless without session
3. The REST API will serve other web applications

There are some potential solutions, but neither is security.

1. Base Auth, the browser hold the username/password
2. Token with expiry timestamp, the problem is user could stay on the page until token expires

So, is there a way to protect the REST API when calling it from AJAX?

Comment: Protecting the API from who or what? From web server users? From complete strangers? From XSS? From CSRF?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly I may suggest you use the Token solution. In order to maintain security you may generate new token on every request (& send it to client in response), which should be used to make next request, and disable token if it is once used or has expired.

Sorry, I meant to mention it as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.